# AついたB - Is there a general grammatical structure here?

Tags: grammar

ウソついた証拠 is a line from Attack on Titan's first episode.  It's roughly translated as "proof of lying".  Is there a general grammatical pattern that we can derive from this AついたB?

Comment: Do you know the term 嘘をうく? That's all this is.

Comment: Not familiar, can you catch me up?

Comment: Any J-J or J-E dictionary contains this phrase. https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%81%9D%E3%82%92%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F

Comment: Hmm, I got a 403 error with that, and Jisho didn't give me any results which is why I asked.  Was the original comment you made meant to be Uku or Tsuku?

Comment: I assume it was meant to be Tsuita which in that case It would mean to tell a lie, so I guess this is just a Noun Phrase.  "Told a lie" proof.

Comment: Apologies, I made a typo. It is indeed 嘘をつく.

Comment: 嘘をついた is a relative clause with the subject omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special here. 嘘をつく is a very common set phrase meaning "to tell a lie". つく happens to be the verb you must use with 嘘, and you have to learn this by rote. See [light verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/42912/8629). (嘘を言う is understandable, but sounds a bit awkward.)

So 嘘をついた is "(Someone) told a lie", and 嘘をついた証拠 is "the proof that (someone) told a lie" (嘘ついた modifies 証拠 as a relative clause). を has been omitted in your actual example.

On a side note, つく/づく is also a suffix that forms various lexicalized verbs (eg 気付く, むかつく, 色付く, 怖じ気付く), in which case there must not be を before つく. There is no such verb as 嘘つく.